# Is it possible to make a primary key and foriegn key unique together in sqlalchemy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, primary-key, unique-constraint, composite-key

I have my table like this and I want `siteid` and `device` as unique and also there must be a primary key to this table. So I assigned device as primary key.

```
class SiteRoleMapping(db.Model):
    __table_name__ = "site_role_mapping"
    siteid = Column(ForeignKey(('cmp_site.id'), ondelete='CASCADE'), nullable=False)
    device = Column(String, primary_key=True)
    rolename = Column(String)
    description = Column(String, default="None")
```

Comment: Have you tried settings primary_key=True to both the device and siteid?

Comment: Why is "device" a primary key for something called SiteRoleMapping?

Comment: Just give `SiteRoleMapping` a simple integer id as primary key and add a unique constraint on (device, site_id).

Answer (score 2):

Without knowing much about your database, I think you should just give the mapping an Integer Primary Key and add a unique constraint on the two fields you want to have unique.

Like this:

```py
from sqlalchemy import UniqueConstraint

class SiteRoleMapping(db.Model):
    __table_name__ = "site_role_mapping"
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key)
    site_id = Column(ForeignKey('cmp_site.id', ondelete='CASCADE'), nullable=False)
    device = Column(String, primary_key=True)
    rolename = Column(String)
    description = Column(String, default="None")

    # add unique constraint
    __table_args__ = (UniqueConstraint('site_id', 'device'), )
```

However, reading the table name mapping, it sounds like you are implementing a many-to-many relationship between sites and roles. This is usually done using three tables, one for sites, one for roles and one for the mapping

So I would expect a mapping to have two foreign keys, not just one.